# How do I extract only the visible placemarks from a KML?

Tags: convert, kml, xml, google-earth-pro

I've been given a KML file containing over 1000 placemarks, a small subset of which were selected by a user in Google Earth and made visible (by checking the checkbox next to the feature name). I've looked in the KML using a text editor and placemark visibility is set by the `<visibility>` KML tag. Is there a way to save only those features in the KML that are visible, or export them to some other format?

I'd like to generate a table of the features containing the names (lat/longs would be nice too) of only those features that are visible (turned on) in the KML, or at least a table that shows me the Visibility of each placemark so I can filter out the ones that are not visible. I've tried converting the KML using Xtools, ArcGIS' built-in KML conversion, and QGIS and I get a layer containing *all* the features in the KML, even the ones that are turned off. I have Google Earth Pro but haven't found a tool in it to do this.

ETA: One more problem: the feature names are not contained in the placemark's `<name>` tag, they're in a `SimpleData` element.